# change some element of a correlation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I am working on correlation matrices. These matrices have the main property to be symetric , positive-semidefinite, have 1 on the diagonal and each of their elements is between -1 and 1.
Let's say I have a correlation matrix of size N by N, and its (i,j) element is 0.5 . I want to create a new matrix that is as close as possible of the initial one, but with a higher / lower value for (i,j), while still keeping it a correlation matrix.

Is there a general method to do this?